# How execute multiple lists in a true statement?

Tags: conditionals

For this simple question, I never found any answer. Let assume I have the following:

```
(if (true)
    (foo1) ;; When true
    (bar) ;; When false)
```

So I would like to combine foo1 and foo2

```
(if (true)
    (foo1)(foo2) ;; When true
    (bar) ;; When false)
```

The problem is that the Emacs Lisp interpreter consider `foo2` as false statement. Trying to devise some workaround, I could get away with the following:

```
(if (true)
    (foo3) ;; When true
    (bar) ;; When false)

(defun foo3 ()
    (foo1)
    (foo2))
```

But this could be quite cumbersome when you use if-else statements a lot.  How
could I find a more practical way for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `progn` or `prog1`. `progn` takes a list of body forms, evaluates them one by one, then returns the value of the last one. `prog1` does the same but returns the value of the first one.

```
(if (true)
  (progn (foo1)
         (foo2))
  (bar))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Emacs Lisp is so flexible, which makes it difficult to me to keep sight on all available options.